# PyMysql using REGEXP_REPLACE with string parameters (update query for mariaDB)

Tags: python, mysql, regex, mariadb, pymysql

So I wanted to update a table where I have to change the contents of a specific column. For the updated value I need to use RegEx. Fortunately my DB is MariaDB so it has REGEXP_REPLACE support.

Now, I wrote a Python script that should do this: Take a list of strings (say, words) and if a column value starts with one of these strings, delete it. The SQL query should be basically this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '(?i)^(%s\\s+)', '');
```

i.e. I'm doing a case-insensitive match where a specific string (specified by `%s`) followed by any number of spaces occurs in the beginning of the column value.

Now when I try to put this into the script, I'm facing several problems, depending on how I inject the parameter to the query.

1. **Using String interpolation**
   I know this is not the preferred way to do it, but here's how it looks like:

   ```
   sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`column`, '(?i)^(%s\\\\s+)', '');" % (term)
   cursor.execute(sql)
   ```

   When I use this, the `term` gets inserted correctly (I check with `print(cursor.mogrify(sql, (term,)))`), but I run into problems if `term` contains any characters that would have to be escaped in the regex, e.g. `-`.
2. **Using execute with parameters** This is the cleaner option, but I get another problem here - the string gets inserted including quotes. Which breaks the whole statement because it also has quotes in it. So here's the code:

   ```
   sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`column`, '(?i)^(%s\\\\s+)', '');"
   cursor.execute(sql, (term,))
   ```

   But this results in statements like this:

   ```
   UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`column`, '(?i)^('example'\\s+)', '');
   ```

   with a quoted string inside the regex which is also in quotes.

Any suggestions how I can solve this? I need to have the replacement terms inside the regex without quotes, but also if there are any special characters inside the replacement terms, they have to be escaped. Maybe I need to write a separate function for this but I'm not sure. I'm neither very advanced in Python nor in SQL.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Try `% (re.escape(term))` with the first method.

Comment: Seems to be working! Thanks. Sometimes it's the little things....